# what's the difference between arrayListOf and ArrayList in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I searched the difference between arrayListOf and ArrayList.
so I understand arrayListOf is function, and ArrayList is class.
but I don't understand the exact difference using them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ArrayList<String>() vs arrayListOf<String>()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56166712/arrayliststring-vs-arraylistofstring)

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/array-list-of.html) `arrayListOf` is a function that creates an ArrayList instance. If I understand it correctly it serves the purpose of determining the generic type from the passed input values and it's a convenience function.

Comment: Isnt ArrayList a collection of lists? While arrayListOf is a kind of list? https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/

Comment: Thats what i understood in the documentary here :D